# What are some high level networking libraries for C++?

Tags: c++, networking, libraries

I'm completely new to networking as a whole and I have gotten completely lost every time I've tried to begin networking with various libraries (Boost::Asio was barely documented and terrible for beginners, Winsock is extremely low level, Raknet was near impossible to set up and only had 1 tutorial series on the whole library). I'm looking for something high level that's easy to learn with and easy to manipulate.

My uses for the library will be for simple games. I don't necessarily need something that's extremely diverse and flexible, just something that's suitable for my needs. Cross-platform is desired but not necessary.

Comment: Boost.Asio might not be the best for begginers, but it's very well documented.

Comment: There's a networking sub-library in SDL, I have no clue if its any good though.

Comment: @TiloWiklund I use SFML (I used SDL a while ago), which also has a networking library and apparently both are pretty low level. I haven't found many that are good for learning as well though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than those named, I found [enet](http://enet.bespin.org/) to be rather nice to use and very easy to learn. Or - depending on your needs - you could try the networking part of [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) ([SDL_net](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_net/)), but these are bigger libraries offering more than just networking. All three are rather nice regarding their license terms, but if you're bothering about these, I'd recommend enet or SFML.

Comment: I think I'll look at SFML for networking as well. I already use it for graphics, so it's probably best. Hopefully it's as easy to learn as the graphics library. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, in that case go with SFML, unless you need low latency UDP and want to do your own verification (as SFML's UDP stuff is still a bit slow or buggy sometimes as far as I've read).

Comment: The reason I initially didn't look at it was because I heard that it was low level and buggy. After looking it over and reading about it, it seems really easy and simple. I'm definitely going to use it. Thanks a lot, I've been searching for days!

Comment: Just make sure you're using SFML2 over SFML1.6. There's a RC only so far, but there are lots of bug fixes included.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [QtNetwork](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtnetwork.html) module of Qt. You possibly will find other Qt's features useful too.

Comment: I've heard that QT makes SFML and other graphics libraries really slow. If it turns out that QT has good networking then I'll consider it, but I'm not sure how practical that will be. Thanks.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the other large GUI/Frameworks (WxWidgets comes to mind, and I think GTK too) offer similar functionality.